# How to parse XML by xmltype in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing, xmltable

I have a little problem here with the XPath property when I'm trying to parse a XML document.
This is my example:

```
DECLARE
   px_return    XMLTYPE
      := XMLTYPE (
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <h:AxisValues xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:h="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/">
            <User xmlns="">FSCD</User>
            <Solution xmlns="">Multicare</Solution>
            <ApplicationalUser xmlns=""/>
            <ApplicationalUserSystem xmlns=""/>
            <SystemUser xmlns=""/>
            <SystemUserSystem xmlns=""/>
            <Proxy xmlns="">0</Proxy>
        </h:AxisValues>
    </SOAP:Header>
    <SOAP:Body xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <ns1:maintainMandateResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.com/ws/SAP/Finantial/MaintainMandate/V1">
            <return>
                <messageType>E</messageType>
            </return>
        </ns1:maintainMandateResponse>
    </SOAP:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>');

   lv_msgType   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   SELECT Return.msgType
     INTO lv_msgType
     FROM XMLTABLE (
             xmlnamespaces (
                DEFAULT 'enterprise.com/ws/SAP/Finantial/MaintainMandate/V1',
                'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
                'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP",
                'enterprise.com/ws/SAP/Finantial/MaintainMandate/V1' AS "ns1"),
             '//soapenv:Envelope/SOAP:Body/ns1:maintainMandateResponse'
             PASSING px_return
             COLUMNS msgType VARCHAR2 (1) PATH 'messageType') Return;


   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Message type: ' || lv_msgType);
END;
```

I'm getting a NO_DATA_FOUND exception because I can't find results in this parsing method.

I've tried a lot of different strategies, included putting `return` in the PATH or in the XQUery string but with no success.

I think this is a small and simple problem but I am not able to find.
Thanks in advance!
Filipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `urn:` prefix in your `ns1` namespace declaration. You are also ignoring the `<return>` node level, and you have a default namespace which is incorrect as you have child nodes without any namespace. So you need:

```
   SELECT Return.msgType
     INTO lv_msgType
     FROM XMLTABLE (
             xmlnamespaces (
                'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "soapenv",
                'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP",
                'urn:enterprise.com/ws/SAP/Finantial/MaintainMandate/V1' AS "ns1"),
             '/soapenv:Envelope/SOAP:Body/ns1:maintainMandateResponse'
             PASSING px_return
             COLUMNS msgType VARCHAR2 (1) PATH 'return/messageType') Return;
```

Which gets:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Message type: E
```

Or you can also move the return into the XPath of course, which has the same effect here:

```
             '/soapenv:Envelope/SOAP:Body/ns1:maintainMandateResponse/return'
             PASSING px_return
             COLUMNS msgType VARCHAR2 (1) PATH 'messageType') Return;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. It was obviously a small path problem.